# How to plot many 3D lines together

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Here is a small data sample:

```
data = {{{10.5438, -0.224956, -1.09651}, {10.5377, 0.252612, 
0.971822}, {10.636, 0.0170358, -0.961191}, {10.065, 
0.0826926, -4.27159}, {9.06832, 0.513978, -6.88496}, {6.82993, 
0.249625, -13.4183}, {3.41034, 0.966202, -27.087}, {-3.8472, 
0.832591, -24.9483}, {-7.14816, 0.244906, -13.1244}}, {{10.5593,
-0.235618, -1.05413}, {10.5793, 0.223809, 1.27232}, {10.8476,
-0.0543677, 0.775037}, {11.0111, -0.584972, 2.09497}, {12.1732,
-1.50977, 9.90628}, {14.1839, -6.03413, 5.51221}, {12.0181, 
-15.4799, -32.4912}, {0.322652, -23.8757, -82.276}, {-18.1188, 
-21.1508, -91.2322}}}
```

It contains the `(x,y,z)` coordinates of two 3D lines. My question is how to plot these two 3D lines together in the same plot (the points of each line should be connected)? Please take into account that the real data file contains more than 100 sub-lists, so the solution should not be applicable for only two sub-lists.

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[Line /@ data]
```

should work with your data.

or...

```
Graphics3D[{{Red, Line[data[[1]]]}, {Green, Line[data[[2]]]}}]
```

or best...

```
Graphics3D[MapThread[{#1, Line[#2]} &, {{Red, Green}, data}]]
```

For `data` having some arbitrary number of lines...

```
data = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 2}}, 
   {{-5, 4, 3}, {-2, 6, 5}, {-8, 4, 2}, {6, 6, 1}}, 
   {{4, 4, 3}, {9, 2, 5}, {8, -3, 6}, {4, 7, 6}, {9, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 2}}};        
Graphics3D[
     MapThread[{#1, Line[#2]} &, 
     {Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {Length[data]}], data}]]
```

Comment: It was much easier than I thought. Thanks!